# Free Physical Memory

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to create a batch file to get,

Total,Available,Free Physical Memory of my system in a text file.

i tried below in a batch but Free Physical Memory i am not getting through command.

```
systeminfo |find "Total Physical Memory"
systeminfo |find "Available Physical Memory"
systeminfo |find "Free Physical Memory"
```

how i can get Free Physical Memory using batch as i know:

```
Free Physical Memory=Total-(Available+Cache)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
wmic os get FreeVirtualMemory, FreePhysicalMemory, FreeVirtualMemory,MaxProcessMemorySize,TotalVisibleMemorySize,TotalVirtualMemorySize
```

Works faster than systeminfo

Comment: One more point..all these memories are coming in bytes i think..is there any way to convert them in GB in same **wmic** command..?

Comment: yes ,they can be divided by `1 073 741 824` and you can get the modulus and the product with set - > http://ss64.com/nt/set.html .At the moment I have no time to do this , but after 4-5 hours...

Comment: A problem being that batch math could well fail with 8 or 16 GB RAM